# I have a issue with ag grid enterprise floating date filter

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid enterprise but I am facing an issue with the floating date filter(agDateColumnFilter)

there is a dd/mm/yyyy format and when I type 27/02/2 it becomes 27/02/1902 automatically
I don't know why anyone can suggest? if I removed ag-grid-enterprise.min.js then its working fine but I want enterprise features

[image]

Thanks in Advance,

You can find the same issue in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9NAfPeEu8GgJw7okqz77?p=preview&preview)

```
     <ag-grid-vue class="ag-theme-alpine"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :rowData="rowData"
        :groupHeaders="true"
        :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      >
      </ag-grid-vue>
```

script code :

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { AgGridVue},
  data() {
      return {
        
        columnDefs: null,
        rowData: userData.userData,

        gridOptions: {
          headerHeight: 26,
          rowHeight: 26,
          floatingFiltersHeight: 26,
          floatingFilter: true,
          rowSelection: "single",
          rowGroupPanelShow: "always",
        },
      }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.columnDefs = [
          {headerName: 'Id', field: 'id',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
          {headerName: 'Date', field: 'date',filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply'], debounceMs: 2000}},
          {headerName: 'User Name', field: 'username',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
          {headerName: 'Name', field: 'name',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
          {headerName: 'Email', field: 'email',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
          {headerName: 'Zip Code', field: 'address.zipcode',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
          {headerName: 'City', field: 'address.city',filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',filterParams: {buttons: ['clear', 'apply']}},
        ];
    },
}
```

Comment: You're saying what it does. You haven't made clear what you *expected*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever When I am trying to filter date with typing 27/02/ and then just press 2 for type year (yyyy) it becomes 27/02/1902 its change automatically –